# A server side for a Premier League score guessing app

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

So I'm writing a Premier League score prediction app with Python, Flask and SQLalchemy and have almost finished the server side of it. I realised that no one has ever looked at my code and there could be plenty of mistakes that I simply never noticed. Also wondering if there is anything obvious that I'm missing (to do with security, performance, etc.). So I would be grateful if anyone wanted to look at my code and simply tell me what I could do better and how to improve it or if there are any bad dev practices in there.

The code is here: https://github.com/adammarszalek22/pl-server

I'm quite new to this and never posted a question on here so if I missed something then let me know :)

It's asking me for some lines of code so here is app.py

```
import os
import redis
import requests
import json

from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask_smorest import Api
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from datetime import timedelta
from rq import Queue

from db import db
from resources.user import blp as UserBlueprint
from resources.bets import blp as BetsBlueprint
from resources.matches import blp as MatchesBlueprint
from resources.groups import blp as GroupsBlueprint
from resources.admin.admin import blp as AdminBlueprint
from models.blocklist import BlocklistModel
from db import db
from models import MatchesModel, UserModel, GroupsModel
from date_time import convert_to_datetime, has_passed

from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler


def create_app(db_url=None):
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    load_dotenv()
    connection = redis.from_url(
        os.getenv("REDIS_URL")
    )
    app.queue = Queue("example", connection=connection)
    matches_scheduler = APScheduler()
    scheduler = APScheduler()
    group_pos_scheduler = APScheduler()

    
    def get_matches():
        with app.app_context():
            url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/fixtures/'
            request = requests.get(url)
            response = json.loads(request.content)
            for i in response:
                match = MatchesModel.query.filter(
                    MatchesModel.match_id == str(i["code"])
                    ).first()
                if match:
                    match.finished = i["finished"]
                    match.goal1 = i["team_h_score"]
                    match.goal2 = i["team_a_score"]
                    db.session.add(match)
                    db.session.commit()
                else:
                    match = MatchesModel(
                        match_id = i["code"],
                        goal1 = i["team_h_score"],
                        goal2 = i["team_a_score"],
                        start_time = i["kickoff_time"],
                        finished = i["finished"]
                    )
                    db.session.add(match)
                    db.session.commit()
            print('Matches added')
        
    def compare_guesses():
        with app.app_context():
            def compare(a, b, c, d):
                if a == c and b == d:
                    return 3
                elif a > b and c > d:
                    return 1
                elif b > a and d > c:
                    return 1
                elif a == b and c == d:
                    return 1
                else:
                    return 0
            users = UserModel.query.all()
            for user in users:
                for bet in user.bets:
                    match = MatchesModel.query.filter(MatchesModel.match_id == bet.match_id).first()
                    if match and match.finished == True and bet.done == "no":
                        points = compare(bet.goal1, bet.goal2, match.goal1, match.goal2)
                        user.points += points
                        if points == 3:
                            user.three_pointers += 1
                        elif points == 1:
                            user.one_pointers += 1
                        bet.done = "yes"
                        db.session.add(user)
                        db.session.commit()
            print('Points added')
            positions()
        
    def positions():
        with app.app_context():
            teams = {}
            users = UserModel.query.all()
            for user in users:
                teams[user.id] = {}
                teams[user.id]["points"] = int(user.points)
                teams[user.id]["three_pointers"] = int(user.three_pointers)
                teams[user.id]["one_pointers"] = int(user.one_pointers)
            positions = {k: v for k, v in sorted(teams.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1]["points"], item[1]["three_pointers"]), reverse=True)}
            standing = 1
            for player_id in positions.keys():
                user = UserModel.query.get_or_404(player_id)
                user.position = standing
                db.session.add(user)
                db.session.commit()
                standing += 1
            print("Positions done")
    
    def groups_positions():
        with app.app_context():
            groups = GroupsModel.query.all()
            for group in groups: 
                teams = {}
                for user in group.user:
                    teams[user.id] = {}
                    teams[user.id]["points"] = int(user.points)
                    teams[user.id]["three_pointers"] = int(user.three_pointers)
                    teams[user.id]["one_pointers"] = int(user.one_pointers)
                positions = {k: v for k, v in sorted(teams.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1]["points"], item[1]["three_pointers"]), reverse=True)}
                pos = []
                for i in positions.keys():
                    pos.append(i)
                pos_string = ' '.join(map(str, pos))
                group.positions = pos_string
                db.session.add(group)
                db.session.commit()
    scheduler_time = 100
    matches_scheduler.add_job(id = 'Updating matches',
                      func = get_matches,
                      trigger = 'interval',
                      seconds = scheduler_time)
    scheduler.add_job(id = 'Comparing guesses',
                      func = compare_guesses,
                      trigger = 'interval',
                      seconds = scheduler_time)
    group_pos_scheduler.add_job(id = 'Group positions',
                      func = groups_positions,
                      trigger = 'interval',
                      seconds = scheduler_time)
    
    matches_scheduler.start()
    scheduler.start()
    group_pos_scheduler.start()

    app.config["API_TITLE"] = "Premier League REST API"
    app.config["API_VERSION"] = "v1"
    app.config["OPENAPI_VERSION"] = "3.0.3"
    app.config["OPENAPI_URL_PREFIX"] = "/"
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = db_url or os.getenv("DATABASE_URL", "sqlite:///data.db")
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
    app.config["PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS"] = True

    db.init_app(app)
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)
    api = Api(app)

    app.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"] = 'adam' #will be changed later
    app.config["JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES"] = timedelta(hours=1)
    app.config["JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES"] = timedelta(days=30)
    jwt = JWTManager(app)

    @jwt.token_in_blocklist_loader
    def check_if_token_in_blocklist(jwt_header, jwt_payload):
        blocklist_item = BlocklistModel.query.get(jwt_payload['jti'])
        return blocklist_item != None
    
    @jwt.revoked_token_loader
    def revoked_token_callback(jwt_header, jwt_payload):
        return(
            jsonify(
            {'description': 'The token has been revoked',
             'error': 'token_revoked'}
            ),
            401
        )
    
    @jwt.needs_fresh_token_loader
    def token_not_fresh_callback(jwt_header, jwt_payload):
        return(
            jsonify(
            {
                'description': 'The token is not fresh',
                'error': 'fresh_token_required'
            }
            ),
            401
        )

    @jwt.additional_claims_loader
    def add_claims_to_jwt(identity):
        if identity == 'adam1234':
            return {'is_admin': True}
        return {'is_admin': False}


    @jwt.expired_token_loader
    def expired_token_callback(jwt_header, jwt_payload):
        return(
            jsonify(
            {'message': 'The token has expired', 'error': 'token_expired'}
            ),
            401
        )
    
    @jwt.invalid_token_loader
    def invalid_token_callback(error):
        return(
            jsonify(
            {'message': 'Signature verification failed.', 'error': 'invalid_token'}
            ),
            401
        )
    
    @jwt.unauthorized_loader
    def missing_token_callback(error):
        return(
            jsonify(
            {'description': 'Request does not contain an access token', 
             'error': 'authorization_required'}
            ),
            401
        )
    
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    
    api.register_blueprint(UserBlueprint)
    api.register_blueprint(BetsBlueprint)
    api.register_blueprint(MatchesBlueprint)
    api.register_blueprint(GroupsBlueprint)
    api.register_blueprint(AdminBlueprint)

    return app
```

Comment: Hmm, nesting everything within `def create_app` is Weird. There are some Business Rules (like "three pointer") which should be explained by a URL reference. There's no [unit tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) in the OP, and given the highly nested style it appears it would be quite difficult to write `test_compare_guesses()` or any similar automated test.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! It is good that you included the contents of app.py. While they can reference sources from external sites, reviewers can only review code in the post. If you are concerned about the size of your code, bear in mind that [the character limit on Code Review was increased to 65k](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7163/120114).

Comment: @J_H thanks for your response. I initially tried to create those 3 functions in a different file and then import them. But then I kept getting errors saying they have to be in the app context or something like that which is why I had to nest them in the main function. Any ideas on how I can avoid this?